# What features do you expect from a Java (Rich) Client Framework?

Tags: java, swing, frameworks, client

I'm intending to design (and provide a reference implementation for) a new **Swing Rich Client Framework**. My job and personal experience covers many project-specific Swing client frameworks as well as the Eclipse RCP, and every one of them had some original and clever concepts, but also drawbacks and rigid realizations.

My plan is to incorporate the **best of those concepts and features** into a new framework whose core is very open and extendable.

For my *must-have-features* list, I'm counting on your input and hope you can share some **concept pearls & diamonds** you've encountered in other frameworks, or features you always wanted to have or have in a better way.

The framework is intended

- for very simple to very complex and sophisticated projects
- for clients that need full i18n
- for richt clients that execute some or all of the non-presentation logic on the server
- to be very lightweight
- to be easy to learn and use

Thanks in advance for sharing your insights :)

Comment: yikes, another reinvention of the wheel... My personal highest prioritised must-have-feature: a huge and active user community. But that can't be coded...

Comment: Why don't you consider contributing to efforts in other similar projects? As examples, there are BSAF and Guts-GUI, and probably others as well.

Answer (score 2):

Docking views / windows supporting predefined layouts! I have not found any good, easy to use, stable docking framework for java.